# How to cycle through a series of string values in CMD with java?

Tags: java

Essentially I want this to happen:

I open the `Command Prompt` and run my program, and it will say "Hello." Then without inputting anything again, I want to press enter. After that it will say "How are you?".

And just continue, so that every time I press enter it gives a `new string` until I reach the end of the `string cycle`, upon which the program exits.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways to do it:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] str = {"Hi", "Hello", "Done"};  //create an array of words

for(String s : str){        //iterate through all words     
    System.out.print(s);    //display word
    scn.nextLine();         //wait for <enter>
}
```

---

**Program Test:**

```
Hi
Hello
Done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String greet[] = {"Hi", "Hello","How are u ? "};
        int i =0;
        while (sc.nextLine().equals("") && i < greet.length) {
            System.out.println(greet[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you but the answer is rather easy: You just posted code that solves the problem but you did not explain the solution. The question was 'How do I go about this?' and not 'Please do my work and post a working code sample'